# Create SSL certificate non-interactively

Tags: scripting, ssl

I want to silently, non interactively, create an SSL certificate. I.e., without get prompted for any data.

The normal way I create the certificate would be:

```bsh
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
```

I tried the following:

```bsh
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
touch openssl.cnf

cat >> openssl.cnf <<EOF
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = GB
ST = Test State
L = Test Locality
O = Org Name
OU = Org Unit Name
CN = Common Name
emailAddress = test@email.com
EOF

openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -nodes -days 7300 \
    -signkey server.key -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
```

But I still get a prompt for data.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation or output of what is happening instead of the desired result?

Comment: I get the help as a output- Anything is wrong with the parameters here: `openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -nodes -days 7300 -signkey server.key -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem `

Comment: It's best to provide the output of errors when you're having issues. I'm guessing your issue is because of `-signkey`. This is not a valid `openssl req` option on my system. The error message will have this as the very first line: `unknown option -signkey`

Comment: Well that signkey should tell SSL to use the provided key as i know?

Comment: Your "normal way to create the certificate" doesn't prompt for any data. Are you not wanting it to output anything? Then use `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: How does this not work? What behavior do you see, what did you expect instead? If there are error messages, copy-paste them. If the output files are not what you wanted, how do they differ?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The thing you're missing is to include the certificate subject in the `-subj` flag. I prefer this to creating a config file because it's easier to integrate into a workflow and doesn't require cleaning up afterward.

One step key and csr generation:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes \
    -keyout www.example.com.key -out www.example.com.csr \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com"
```

One step self signed passwordless certificate generation:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" \
    -keyout www.example.com.key  -out www.example.com.cert
```

Neither of these commands will prompt for any data.

See my answer to this [nearly identical question](https://superuser.com/q/226192) on Super User.

---

After many years, and by popular demand, here's how to do it with ECDSA.

This is necessarily two steps because EC keys require generating parameters, which (at the time of this writing) must be done separately from signing request*.

```
openssl ecparam -out www.example.com.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -days 365 -nodes -x509 \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" \
    -key www.example.com.key -out www.example.com.cert
```

* You can either just generate ec parameters and use `req -newkey ec:<file with ec params>`, or do it like I did above. There isn't really a significant difference.

Comment: I didn't modify his original config file, as I thought it might be a standin for a more complicated certificate. Some configurations that cannot be represented with a `-subj` parameter, particularly when you get into v3 extensions and subjectAltName parameters.

Comment: You can also use `-batch` (non-interactive mode)

Comment: C                      = GB
 ST                     = Test State or Province
 L                      = Test Locality
 O                      = Organization Name
 OU                     = Organizational Unit Name
 CN                     = Common Name
 emailAddress           = test@email.address

Comment: `ST=denial`, `O=Dis` - wish I could upvote more times

Answer (score 4):

The command you are looking for is:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -config openssl.cnf -nodes -days 7300 -key server.key -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
```

Changes from your version:

- `-new` is required to generate anything
- `-key` used in place of `-signkey`